# Need to understand Dependency Injection in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am a newbie in Angular.js and came across a topic called "**Dependency Injection**". I am totally confused after reading the article.

As per the docs,
*Dependency Injection (DI) is, in angular, method of organizing how components, modules and variables are loaded to various parts of your angular app.*

Here's an example of a dependency injection for a controller:

```
//the controller definition
var Ctrl = function($scope, $http, $location) 
{
  //now you can use any of the injected variables

  //to change the URL after something has happened then you can use $location
  $location.path('/path/to/new/page');
}
  //and now the injection of the variables
  Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$location'];
```

I guess "`Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$location'];`" this is where Dependency Injection comes into picture.

But I need to understand, what it does and how it is useful?

Thanks.

Comment: It simply injects modules you would want to use in your controller, factory, service, etc. In your example, if you aren't using `$http`, then you would just omit it from the injection, and if you needed something, say `ngRoute` parameters then you would inject `$routParams`, etc.

Comment: Fair warning, you will see a variety of different injection techniques. In your example your controller function parameters must match `Ctr.$inject` in order and contents.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection allows you to do several things, first it allows for you to specify only what you need in your `controller`, `factory`, `service`, etc.

You have a lot of pre-baked options but injection also allows you to incorporate 3rd party Angular modules into your project.

For example, let's say you want to use animations and routing, but you want to use ui-router instead of `ngRoute` than you would inject them into your app instantiation.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);
```

---

Now let's say you have your first controller setup.

But let's say you have a service that you want to use in that controller that handles all of your ajax calls using promises.

First the service would be setup with injecting `$http` to make the server request and `$q` for the promises.

```
// It is important to note that not all modules have a scope, 
// so injecting scope into this service would cause a fatal error, 
// it is important to become familiar with what baked in modules allow for 
// injections.
myApp.service('myAjax', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getUsers: function () {
            var q = $q.defer();
            $http.get('my/url/path').success(function (results) {
                // We got a successful response so pass on the results
                q.resolve(results);
            }).error(function (errorResults) {
                // Something went wrong, let's pass that along
                q.reject(errorResults);
            });
            return q.promise;
        }
    }    
});
```

Now that we have the service setup, we would inject that into our controller so we can easily use it to get the users or do anything else we declared in there:

```
// Note that I am demonstrating a different injection approach, this is actually the recommended approach
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myAjax', function ($scope, myAjax) {
    // call our service
    myAjax.getUsers().then(
        function (results) {
            // Here we are using our controller $scope injection to 
            // bind to the html
            $scope.users = results;
        },
        function (error) {},
    )
}]);
```

---

**Edit**

`$inject` is part of `$injector` which you can find [more information here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector).

`$injector` gets instances of everything that has been injected and `$inject` just allows you to setup the injection parameters. `$injector` runs behind the scenes.

[Here is a snippet from the angular source on github - Line 1238](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js)

```
angular.module('ngAppStrictDemo', [])
// BadController will fail to instantiate, due to relying on automatic function annotation,
// rather than an explicit annotation
    .controller('BadController', function($scope) {
        $scope.a = 1;
        $scope.b = 2;
    })
    // Unlike BadController, GoodController1 and GoodController2 will not fail to be instantiated,
    // due to using explicit annotations using the array style and $inject property, respectively.
    .controller('GoodController1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.a = 1;
        $scope.b = 2;
    }])
    .controller('GoodController2', GoodController2);
function GoodController2($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
}
GoodController2.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Comment: $inject is part of $injector which you can find more [information here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector). $injector gets instances of everything that has been injected and $inject just allows you to setup the injection parameters

Answer (score 0):

I want to share of what I thought was a really great example of DI. I'm taking [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) example from the Angular.js documentation.

```
angular.module('xmpl.service', [])

  .value('greeter', {
    salutation: 'Hello',
    localize: function(localization) {
      this.salutation = localization.salutation;
    },
    greet: function(name) {
      return this.salutation + ' ' + name + '!';
    }
  })

  .value('user', {
    load: function(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  });

angular.module('xmpl.directive', []);

angular.module('xmpl.filter', []);

angular.module('xmpl', ['xmpl.service', 'xmpl.directive', 'xmpl.filter'])

  .run(function(greeter, user) {
    // This is effectively part of the main method initialization code
    greeter.localize({
      salutation: 'Bonjour'
    });
    user.load('World');
  })

  .controller('XmplController', function($scope, greeter, user){
    $scope.greeting = greeter.greet(user.name);
  });
```

This code defines a separate module for directive, filter and service. 
As written in the documentation:

> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method.

So, the xmpl module has 3 dependencies which are injected using DI.