# AngularJS Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, code-injection

I am a beginner in angularjs, I start learning by their tutorial, but when comes to dependency injection, I am not quite understand what it means

```
function SomeClass(greeter) {
  this.greeter = greeter;
}

SomeClass.prototype.doSomething = function(name) {
  this.greeter.greet(name);
}
```

In the above example SomeClass is not concerned with creating or locating the greeter dependency, it is simply handed the greeter when it is instantiated.

This is desirable, **but it puts the responsibility of getting hold of the dependency on the code that constructs SomeClass.**

What actually does the bolded sentence mean?

"The code that construct SomeClass", does that mean the **function SomeClass(greeter)**?

Thanks all for the advice

Comment: I think it means `var some = new SomeClass(greeterInstance)`. So the responsibility of this code is to provide proper `greeterInstance` object implementing `greeter` interface.

Comment: @dfsq explanation is totally right. The other way around: If your  `greeterInstance` doesn't match the greeter interface (e.g. a greet method) `some.doSomething()` will throw an error. This tightly coupling is what DI solves.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494233/need-to-understand-dependency-injection-in-angular-js

Comment: @dfsq Totally understood, thanks for the brilliant explanation! Nice and clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `function SomeClass(greeter)` is a constructor function.

The code that constructs `SomeClass` is in this context whatever code does (something along the lines of)

```
var greeter = new Greeter();
var someInstance = new SomeClass(greeter);
```

This is typically somewhere in the DI framework code.

The bottom part is just (one of several) ways of declaring a member-function on a class in Javascript.

```
SomeClass.prototype.doSomething = function(name) {
  this.greeter.greet(name);
}
```

All that does is make sure that every instance of `SomeClass` has a `doSomething` function. For the purpose of explaining DI that part is completely irrelevant.